# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I error return by Android Studio ...i import this project for eclipse project to android studio.. Log Cat:

```
7-26 13:51:07.008    1761-1761/...tutorial E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ....tutorial, PID: 1761
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...tutorial/...tutorial.SimpleListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
```

Any Idea ? Thanks ...

Comment: What is your lock variable?

Comment: I needd more information of source code, o you try to read some file on onCreate Acivity method?

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole stacktrace? I wouldn't expect `java.io.Reader.<init>` to be the first call on a stack. (In most cases everything that follows `Caused by` is much more interesting than what comes before)

Comment: JOSEPH HOW I CAN CONTACT YOU?

Answer (score 4):

You are calling InputStreamReader (or some such function) with a null parameter.

```
    is = new InputStreamReader(null);    // bang
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL pointer exceptions generally occurs when you try to access the object before it has been created that is why it is returning NULL pointer Exception or if you explicitly set the value of object to null..

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem. It was due to InputStream object being null.